# Getting FileError when trying to use the HTML5 file api in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fileapi, html5-filesystem

I was trying to create a file using the file system API in chrome. Initially I tried PERSISTENT storage as follows

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, 
    function(grantedBytes) {
        window.requestFileSystem(webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, 
        errorHandler);
    }, 
    errorHandler);
```

It was working fine initially. But now when I try the same code is giving me the following error

```
NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9
```

Then I tried TEMPORARY file storage as follows

```
window.requestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

That is giving me some FileError with the code 2 which means Security Error. Can anyone please help me on these issues?

Comment: Could the second error actually be from your `onInitFs` callback doing something illegal with your DOMFileSystem object?

Comment: No the program control is not reaching onInitFs. I tried using the `webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota` function before requesting for a quota. This is returning 0 bytes as the available bytes. That is the issue i guess. Is there any way to get quota? Why is this 0 for me?

Comment: Try adding `unlimitedStorage` to your permissions and see if it helps.  If not, I'm really not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Adding `unlimitedStorage` helps to get the quota. But still the FileError haunts me when I try to call `getFile`

Comment: Where exactly are you making the request?  Background page, popup, or content script?

Comment: I'm trying it in a content script

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to place the code in a page that is stored on your local computer and run it with Chrome? Did you add the flag

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

in your Chrome shortcut? I happened to encounter the same error as yours and suddenly I realized that I forgot to add this flag to run my chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error.  I made a simple extension that uses the filesystem API in a content script and it works fine for me.  Do you get any errors on your console?  If not, build off this code and see if you get any more errors.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Testing FS",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches":["*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js":["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**script.js:**

```
webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
    console.log("bytes granted: ", grantedBytes);
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler)
}, errorHandler);

function errorHandler(e) {
  console.log("FS error", e);
}

function onInitFs(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
      console.log(fileEntry);
  }, errorHandler);
}
```