# writing to a file from chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I need to write to a file from my chrome extension. I read that I can use html5 file API for that. I copied a simple piece of code I found online but it gets FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR exception.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    var gig=tab.url;
    var server_url="";
    if(lst_frame.length > 0){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(lst_frame, null, 2));

window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem; 
function errorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  };
  alert(msg);
  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}   
function onInitFs(fs) {
alert("1111");
  fs.root.getFile('/tmp/log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
  alert("222");
    // fileEntry.isFile === true
    // fileEntry.name == 'log.txt'
    // fileEntry.fullPath == '/log.txt'

  }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10517775/2698119 might help you

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your code if `/tmp/log.txt` is an absolute path on your Linux box, or a relative path from the HTML5 storage area, so I'll just remind you that the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api) say that:

> This specification defines an API to navigate file system hierarchies, and defines a means by which a user agent may expose **sandboxed sections** of a user's local filesystem to web applications.

So you can't write your file anywhere on the disk.

Regarding your question, you simply need to create the `/temp` directory first:

```
function onInitFs(fs) 
{
  fs.root.getDirectory('/tmp', {create: true}, function() {}, errorHandler);
  fs.root.getFile('/tmp/log.txt', {create: true}, function() {}, errorHandler);
}
```